# How to send push notification when content on a website changes

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification, execution

The core of the app I am building is that it sends a push notification to the user twice a week with a number from a website, at a specific time twice a week (example of the Swift code I'm using for this below).

I did some research about background execution, but I think I will not be able to use it because it's so limited (only for location, limited time, etc.).
Using a server is another option. I do not intend to make money with this app so it has to be a free option. That's why I was looking into Firebase.

I'm learning Swift now, it's the first programming language I'm learning.

Does anyone have an opinion on how to go about doing this?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.



    let url = URL(string: "https://store.nike.com/be/nl_nl/pd/air-vapormax-flyknit-hardloopschoen-heren/pid-11384993/pgid-12169774")!

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url)

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
        data, response, error in

        var message = ""

        if error != nil {

            print(error)

        } else {

            if let unwrappedData = data {

                let dataString = NSString(data: unwrappedData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)

                var stringSeperator = "exp-pdp-local-price js-pdpLocalPrice"

                if let contentArray = dataString?.components(separatedBy: stringSeperator) {

                    if contentArray.count > 0 {

                        stringSeperator = "€"

                        let newContentArray = contentArray[1].components(separatedBy: stringSeperator)

                        if newContentArray.count > 0 {

                            message = newContentArray[0]

                            print(message)


                        }



                    }

                }

            }

        }

        if message == "" {

            message = "The jackpot couldn't be found. Please try again."

        }

        DispatchQueue.main.sync(execute: {

            //De text in het label van de weer app = message
            //Gebruik 'self.' om naar de viewcontroller te verwijzen, want hier zit je in een closure en niet in de viewcontroller zelf.

        })

    }

    task.resume()


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

Comment: This is definitely not a client side task. Polling another website frequently that you have no access over to receive changes on that website ASAP is a task that should be done on server side.

Comment: Thank you for your input!! What language is needed to let the server do what I wrote in the Swift code above? I was looking into the new 'Cloud Functions' for Firebase..

Comment: To learn how to send a push notification from Cloud Functions for Firebase, see [this example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#notify_users_when_something_interesting_happens). Then to learn how to trigger a Cloud Function on a schedule, see [this blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/how-to-schedule-cron-jobs-with-cloud.html) or watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CbE2PzvAMxA).

Comment: Thank you so much. That'll keep mee busy for a while ;)

Answer (score 2):

Push notifications are not complicated.

Basically you have to register your device to APNS ( Apple push notification system ), once registered device, APNS will return you a token (each token is device unique). When u get the token from APNS you have to send the token to the server which will provide your devices with push notifications. Once the server app receives a token from device, you can save it in database.
For example :

username1 mobile_token1, mobile_token2.

Now, you can get tokens from database for specific username and send push notifications from the server to the devices.

When you send push notifications from server to devices, you have to send the token and data content to APNS, APNS then will send notification to specific device.

So the answer for your question is, if you want to send push notifications you have to send them from backend to devices, the moment you will send push notifications is when the web content changes, you get the tokens from the database, and send notifications to APNS.

The logic is same when you use firebase instead APNS.

Here is a nice tutorial for client side

https://www.raywenderlich.com/156966/push-notifications-tutorial-getting-started

Answer (score 0):

It seems you don't need a push notification (also called remote notification) but a local one ([see apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/SchedulingandHandlingLocalNotifications.html)).

You can configure when during week you want this local notification to be fired.

Edit: I did not catch that content of notifications depends on your previous piece of code.
So you can still use a local notification. It will be triggered by what is called a background fetch.
See [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/143128/background-modes-tutorial-getting-started) for example (search 'Background fetch' on the page).

Comment: The thing is that the notification only needs to be fired after the piece of code that I've written above is executed. After this execution there will be a number that is returned, based on that number there needs to be sent a push notification or not. So the push notification maybe can be local, but than the problem still is the background execution of the code, am I right?
Sorry if this is not clear.

Comment: Ok your use case is clearer now. I edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you for the edit. I looked into the tutorial you recommended. I have a few concerns with the background fetch. Does it work when the app is completely killed in the background? And if that is possible, is it possible to set the time interval to 3 days?

Comment: not sure if it works when app is killed. It is not possible to set time interval at all, but when your app is woke up you can check if last call is 3 days old or not.